# Merging SQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a walkthrough author for games. I am trying to display all rows that match all criterias. Currently, the table displays results from each of the tables but I want to merge these results so that if the search criteria matches all that the user input, it only returns rows that match it. What's the best way to achieve this? I was trying to use AND before the UNION clauses but it gives me error #1064.

Let's have this sample table.

```
+--------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+
| FAQ_ID |        FAQ_Title        |    Game    |  Platforms   |
+--------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+
|     32 | General Walkthrough FAQ | WWE        | PS2, PSP, DS |
|     34 | Early EXP Farming FAQ   | Digimon    | PS4, PS Vita |
|     35 | General Walkthrough FAQ | Toy Story  | PS1          |
|     36 | General Walkthrough FAQ | Metal Slug | DS           |
+--------+-------------------------+------------+--------------+
```

Then I have this code

```
SELECT FAQ_ID, FAQ_Title, Game, Platforms FROM faqlist WHERE FAQ_Title 
LIKE 'General Walkthrough%' 
AND UNION
SELECT FAQ_ID, FAQ_Title, Game, Platforms FROM faqlist WHERE Platforms = '%DS%'
AND UNION
SELECT FAQ_ID, FAQ_Title, Game, Platforms FROM faqlist WHERE Game = 'Metal Slug' 
ORDER BY FAQ_ID ASC;
```

This should only return the row with FAQ_ID of 36 and eliminates the rest.

Comment: Hint: some `OR`'s in `WHERE` or remove `AND` before `UNION`.

Comment: Just normalise.

Comment: I wanted to display a result that matches all criterias. If the user input type as general walkthrough, a game as Metal Slug and platforms as DS, it should only display the row of FAQ_ID 36. 32, 34 and 35 shouldn't be shown since it doesn't match the criteria

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the OR or AND Condition like this:

```
SELECT FAQ_ID, FAQ_Title, Game, Platforms
FROM faqlist 
WHERE
  FAQ_Title LIKE 'General Walkthrough%' 
OR
  Platforms = '%DS%'
OR
  Game = 'Metal Slug' 
ORDER BY FAQ_ID ASC;
```

Comment: Yes but would this be possible using `UNION` clause?